# execute an action without calling its view in Cakephp 3.x.x

Tags: php, controller, cakephp-3.0

Is there a way to just execute an action inside a controller without the request of its view.

I'm using cakephp 3.x.x

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just turn off the view [controller docs](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html):

```
$this->autoRender = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

In CakePHP version >= 3.6

```
$this->disableAutoRender();
```